# How to do reflection without System.Reflection? i.e. build custom reflection classes?

Tags: .net, reflection, system.reflection

I know this is a rather academic question, but I wonder how one would go about reflecting without `System.Reflection`.

I guess more to the point, I want to know how the `System.Reflection` class is working. Could one create custom classes that also know how load and then decode assemblies to grab the metadata, etc. How would that be done?

Or maybe System.Reflection compiles down to CIL functions that we don't directly have access to in C#/.NET?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source?

Comment: No not yet. That would be work!  :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply take a look at the source of [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).